# How to describe PasswordValidator rules

Tags: .net, security, passwords, asp.net-identity

The Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordValidator is configurable with a number of parameters which define the minimum password length and complexity rules. If the user enters a password that does not meet the criteria, PasswordValidator will throw an exception which describes the violation, but it provides no other way to describe the rules to a user (e.g. "Passwords must be 8-12 characters and must include ..." etc).

I searched StackOverflow and the web in general figuring there must be hundreds of examples out there of what I need, but it's beginning to look like I'm the only person who has ever needed this, which I know isn't the case. Before I write my own implementation, I just have to ask...

Am I completely overlooking an accepted "standard" answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with since I needed to get something working, and wasn't finding the canned standard answer I was looking for. I implemented it as an extension over the PasswordValidator class for convenience, although that's not strictly necessary.

```
public static string ToDescription(this PasswordValidator validator)
{
    var options = new List<string>();
    if (validator.RequireUppercase) options.Add("upper-case letters");
    if (validator.RequireLowercase) options.Add("lower-case letters");
    if (validator.RequireDigit) options.Add("numbers");
    if (validator.RequireNonLetterOrDigit) options.Add("special characters");

    var result = "Passwords must be at least " 
        + validator.RequiredLength + " characters long"
        + (options.Any() ? ", and include " + options.OxfordJoin() : ".");

    return result;
}
```

I also added the OxfordJoin extension to turn the list of requirements into a nicely formatted sentence:

```
public static string OxfordJoin(this IEnumerable<string> source)
{
    var array = source.ToArray();
    var joined = string.Join(", ", array);
    var result = (array.Length > 2)
        ? joined.ReplaceLast(",", ", and")
        : joined.ReplaceLast(",", " and");

    return result;
}
```

...and finally a "so standard it should just be in the framework already" ReplaceLast implementation:

```
public static string ReplaceLast(this string value, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    var position = value.LastIndexOf(oldValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    var result = (position > -1)
        ? value.Substring(0, position) + newValue + value.Substring(position + 1)
        : value;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may sound a bit hackish but sending an empty string to ValidateAsync() method of PasswordValidator will do the work. Example of UserManager with default configuration :

```
var rules = await UserManager.PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync("");

rules.Errors.First() : 
Passwords must be at least 6 characters. 
Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. 
Passwords must have at least one digit ('0'-'9'). 
Passwords must have at least one lowercase ('a'-'z'). 
Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z').
```

you can even list them

```
var list = rules.Errors.First().Split('.');
```

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure I could call that THE answer do to the unusual and somewhat unfriendly phrasing of the resulting paragraph. I'm trying to generate a friendly explanation of the rules like you see on most sites. I was hesitant to post this question, assuming that a hundred people would all tell me "Use the Foo class, everyone knows that", but it looks like there is no standard answer to this one. Most sites probably just write the explanation directly into the page source, perhaps.

Comment: Ugh. "...due to the unusual..." Don't you hate when you find grammatical errors after it's too late to edit your comment?